# Can't Install psycopg2 on Azure

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, psycopg2

I am creating a pipeline with a python script on Azure Web Service.

My script uses psycopg2 to connect to the postgres database

but I am getting an error trying to import psycopg2 saying

`from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa`
`ImportError: /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PQencryptPasswordConn`

any help would be apprciated

Comment: "Azure web services" doesn't tell us much.  What OS and version?  How did you install python?  How did you install psycopg2?

Answer (score 0):

`PQencryptPasswordConn` was introduced in PostgreSQL v10. So you must be trying to use psycopg2 with a libpq that is older than that.

The solution is to upgrade your PostgreSQL client.

Comment: I checked the version and it is the latest version, I still get the error, I don't know why

Comment: No, it isn't. There are probably more than one `libpq.so` on your system, and you accidentally use the wrong one.

Comment: Sorry if I sound naive, I am trying to solve this since yesterday, do you know how I can make sure it uses the correct libpq.so?

Comment: You could use `ldd` on the psycopg2 shared library to see which libpq is uses. You could run `find` or `locate` to find all `libpq.so.*` on your machine.